# Get 0th element FormControl inside Form Array, angular8

Tags: angular

i have a simple reactive form

```
this.orderForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  vlanFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
    vlanId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.positiveInteger)]],
    vlanName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.vlanNamePattern)]],
    addVlanToTrunk: [''],
    trunkInterfaces: this._formBuilder.array([
      this.createAddVlanToTrunkMember()
    ])
  })



    createAddVlanToTrunkMember(): FormGroup {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          trunkInterface: [''],
          allowedVlansOnTrunk: ['']
        });
      }

  get trunkInterfaces(): FormArray {
    return this.vlanFormGroup.get('trunkInterfaces') as FormArray;
  }



get vlanFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.orderForm.get("vlanFormGroup") as FormGroup;
  }
```

I have added a new formControl array using ts. Now i want to access the first row inside `trunkInterfaces` form control array, and get its form controls and their values. I tried `component.trunkInterfaces[0].get('trunkInterface'))`, but its not working. Please help

Comment: What's `component` in `component.trunkInterfaces[0].get('trunkInterface'))`?

Comment: actually i trying inside .spec.ts, writing UT

Comment: OK, in that case where's the `trunkInterfaces` property on the component?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add getters

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the form array `controls` property instead:

```js
component.trunkInterfaces.controls[0].get('trunkInterface'));
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czfuhm (open the console)